# Is there a way to automatically populate a navigation bar with content based on anchors found in the content?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a Bootstrap frontend for this project.

The work I'm doing involves a lot of generated content and code that keeps things very easy to work with. I'm attempting to determine if it's possible to generate a navigational structure (within a framework) based on tags like the following:

```
<h2 id="_foo_bar">Foo Bar</h2>
<h2 id="_metrics_collection">Metrics Collection</h2>
```

And fill a structure like this:

```
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
          <li class="sidebar-brand">
              <a href="#_foo_bar">Foo Bar</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#_metrics_collection>Metrics Collection</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could try cycling over each heading element and append a link to the navigation for each like...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("h2").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text()
    var id = $(this).attr("id")
    var navLink = "<li><a href='#" + id + "'>" + text + "</a></li>"
    $("#nav").append(navLink)
  }) 
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    
  <ul id="nav">
  
  </ul>

  <h2 id="someId1" class="subject">Some Heading</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat, dolore. Repellat similique doloremque nisi, accusamus deleniti magni ut iure. Nesciunt quisquam accusamus, facilis, excepturi saepe repudiandae distinctio. Suscipit ipsam, maxime.</p>
  <h2 id="someId2" class="subject">And Another</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat, dolore. Repellat similique doloremque nisi, accusamus deleniti magni ut iure. Nesciunt quisquam accusamus, facilis, excepturi saepe repudiandae distinctio. Suscipit ipsam, maxime.</p>
  <h2 id="someId3" class="subject">And Another One</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat, dolore. Repellat similique doloremque nisi, accusamus deleniti magni ut iure. Nesciunt quisquam accusamus, facilis, excepturi saepe repudiandae distinctio. Suscipit ipsam, maxime.</p>
```

http://jsbin.com/gukoxizaqa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This is great!! Thanks so much for sharing. Quick question - if I wanted to do this also for <h3> tags, how would I make sure it gets placed under the parent? I included in this jsbin my current navigational structure: http://jsbin.com/luyutilayo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: You're welcome.  Not sure I'm fully clear on your question regarding the h3 tags being placed under the parent, the jsbin looks like maybe you got it working?

Comment: Not quite, the issue is that with the current code, every h3 is appended after all of the h2 tags. E.g. if you have 3 h2 tags and 2 h3 tags, it lists all three h2 tags and then the two h3. What I'd like it to do is if there's an h2 with a h3 before the next h2, it should append the h3 as a child class of that h2. (sorry this is confusing)